# Different vertex/index formats in a single buffer

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d, direct3d11

In my scene, I have several static models that never change. Some models only have float3 vertices and 16 bit indices, some are more complex, have colors and normals in vertices, and 32-bit indices.

Q1. Can I combine them all in a single vertex and index buffers, and draw like this:

```
// Model #1 has only position and 16 bit indices
const int model1verts = 20, model1indices = 100;
UINT stride1 = sizeof( Vector3 ), offset1 = 0;
context->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &vb, &stride1, &offset1 );
context->IASetIndexBuffer( ib, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0 );
context->DrawIndexed( model1indices, 0, 0 );
// Set another shader + input layout here

// Model #2 has positions + normals, and 32 bit indices
const int model2verts = 200, model2indices = 500;
UINT stride2 = sizeof( Vector3 ) * 2, offset2 = stride1 * model1verts;
context->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &vb, &stride2, &offset2 );
context->IASetIndexBuffer( ib, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, model1indices * sizeof( uint16_t ) );
context->DrawIndexed( model2indices, 0, 0 );
// 20 more models to follow, all from the same buffers
```

Q2. AFAIK, GPUs loves aligned data. When calling IASetVertexBuffers/IASetIndexBuffer, those offsets, should they be a multiple of 4 or 16 bytes? Documentation doesn’t say that.

Q3. Should I do that at all? Will this save resources compared to 20-100 smaller buffers each of it’s own format?

Comment: On your Q1: Technically I think it should work. However, I guess there will be no real benefit and it will probably make things more complicated by having a heterogeneous buffer. I would suggest putting the models with similar layouts together in one buffer. Furthermore, you can try to convert them (i.e. use R32 for all index buffers). If they are just small models the overhead will probably not really matter..

Comment: @JackWhite ok thank for your input, for now I decided to only merge same vertex formats.